# stringWithContentsOfURL different result with wifi

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring

I have the following code:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error];
```

and I get a different string using Wifi than with my mobile network.. Basically it's the same, but I get it without the spaces.. just like this in wifi:

```
<html> hello </html>
```

would be this with my mobile network:

```
<html>hello</html>
```

how can this be?

I am using iPhone SDK 6.0 and Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Does using `NSUTF8Encoding` produce better results?

Comment: no difference, I guess it's the problem that Haris Hussain postet, but I do not know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because, when you try to get data using mobile data, the information in the header is sent that the request has been with mobile data, so it tries to minimize the response, and thats not the case with wifi, it doesn't try to minimize the response while using wifi.

Comment: and how can I fix it? or in other words, is there a way to fix it?